# UPDATE database using mysqli prepared?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using the following code to update the database. this is a `mysqli prepared statement`. 
I don't get any error's but it doesn't update the database either!

could someone let me know what's missing in my code please?

```
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {
    include "config/connect.php";
    $targetID = $_GET['edit'];
    $product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['product_name']);


    if ($stmt = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE $storeShop SET product_name = ?  WHERE id = ?")){
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $product_name, $targetID);  

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else {
        //Error
        printf("Prep statment failed: %s\n", $db_conx->error);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where should you get an error? You don't implement any error handling or detection...

Comment: @arkascha, the PHP error's I meant.

Comment: Dump `$product_name` and `$targetID`. Most likely there is not really an id in there as you do expect.

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you're using `bind_param`.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I have all that error reporting on my page. not sure what I have to get from that page you sent me. second, the $storeShop comes from the database. stored in the database. that works because I have `SELECT FROM $storeShop` and `INSERT INTO $storeShop` on the same page and they work just fine..

Comment: @arkascha He has error handling on the `prepare()` call. If there's a syntax error in the SQL, that's where it would be reported.

Comment: @arkascha, impossible, I echo the ID and product_name on the same page with the update statement and it works fine. so I know they exist.

Comment: @Barmar, let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Go ahead, but it's not going to fix anything.

Comment: I'd say that line _would have to be_ `if (FALSE!==($stmt=$db_conx->prepare("UPDATE $storeShop SET product_name = ?  WHERE id = ?"))){`...

Comment: @Barmar, ah I thought that would fix my issue lol

Comment: @arkascha That's not necessary. If `prepare` succeeds it returns a `mysql_statement` object, which is truthy.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, you have some serious issues and I suggest you show yourself to GP, you power trip "downvote" hungry dummy. I fixed it anyway. people like you shouldn't even be allowed to use stackoverflow.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, you can downvote as much as you want but you know it and I know it that i have more knowledge than you will ever have dummy. ;) now piss off..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is how I fixed it:

I added a hidden input field like so:

```
<input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>" />
```

and I added this code at the top of my code:

```
$pid = $_POST['thisID'];
```

and finally I  changed this line in my code:

```
$stmt->bind_param('si', $product_name, $pid);
```

and everything works just fine.

I hope this helps someone.